# date showing 01/01/1970 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date

In my form i have date field but not mandatory(require) when someone forget to fill the date field it get 01/01/1970 by default in database , it not good , i want when it happens it show no date selected i am using this function but its not working any help

```
            <?php 
            function getDateFormat($date){
                if($date == '0000-00-00'){
                    return 'No Date Selected.';
                }
                else {
                    return date('d-m-Y',strtotime($date));
                }
            }
               ?>
```

Comment: why you can not use default value as null...?

Comment: Its not MySQL which taking default as 01/01/1970, its php. I think making date field default NULL will also not work.
compare if($date == '1970-01-01')
         return NULL;

Comment: is `$date` a `datetime` or a `date` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if($date == '0000-00-00')
```

with

```
if($date == '0000-00-00' || $date == NULL)
```

Comment: better yet: `if (!date('U', strtotime($date)))`

Answer (score 2):

Allow Null to date field in database. And also you can set default value for date field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your date field is a `datetime`. Try with

```
if($date == '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your value in `if` condition, and also set allow in DB to NULL

```
    if($date == '0000-00-00'){
     return NULL;
   }
```